# Runtime NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/SparkConf despite compiling fine

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark, sbt

I've got the following simple code that I'm trying to run:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object WordCounter {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Word Counter").setMaster("local")
  }
}
```

It is able to compile fine, but when i run it I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/SparkConf
```

Which is pretty surprising since (1) I've got the `import` statement right there and (2) this was previously working.

I'm pretty sure this is because I recently changed my `sbt` files in the following way:

## build.sbt

```
name := "SparkPlayground"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "com.github.scala-incubator.io" %% "scala-io-core" % "0.4.3"
libraryDependencies += "com.github.scala-incubator.io" %% "scala-io-file" % "0.4.3"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-streaming" % "2.7.0"

//added below 2 lines:
assemblyJarName in assembly := s"${name.value.replace(' ','-')}-${version.value}.jar"
assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = false)
```

## project/assembly.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.3")
```

Im rather new to sbt, but I think whats going on is that I need to create an uber jar of some sort and run everything from that context. Instead I'm directly calling the generated class. However, I don't see any uber jar created in my Intellij project.

How do I properly build and run this project, preferably via Intellij options and not manual SBT console commands?

Comment: You flagged spark as provided, are you sure you actually provide it at runtime ?

Comment: @C4stor Not sure honestly. How can I confirm that?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg remove provided and see if it works

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. Thanks. How do I get the provided flag working via Intellij?

Comment: You need to have Spark somewhere and add it to your classpath, preferably launch everything with spark-submit. I don't know how to do it, I use provided shell scripts at work ;)